# Help identify 12” spigot internals replacement

Tags: plumbing, replacement, spigot

I need to identify the spigot so I can replace the internal stem system. Previous home owner did not make it easy to remove the spigot all together so I’m looking to replace the internal parts only. Once I know the make and model I can buy it and fit it for the internals. The big problem here is previous owner cemented the hell out of it and the vinyl is stuck. Idk how I’ll get to it without making a mess of the vinyl siding.

[image][image][image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if anyone could identify the make and model of this and if they could, you probably wouldn't be able to find just the internal parts. At the end of the pipe your piece slides in a valve seat which could be bad.

This type of spigot or sillcock is about 12" long and is sold as a complete assembly. The handle at the front turns the shaft inside the pipe which, in turn,  opens the valve at the end. The end, which is indoors, is where you tighten or loosen the entire fixture to your water pipe. Hope this helps. See below for an example:

[image]

Comment: The big problem here is previous owner cemented the hell out of it and the vinyl is stuck. Idk how I’ll get to it without making a mess of the vinyl siding.

Comment: Have you located the end of it in your house?  If you turn it there it should loosen  and you could pull it out.  The siding is split at the bottom, try to work it out. If not, you will have to trip the siding a bit.

Comment: Hey Jack, yeah I found the other end inside my house. Thinking you may be right, hoping if I unscrew from inside house first maybe the concrete will crumble. I was thinking about tackling the two screws on the outside of the house which I can't even get to. Chances are there aren't even screws on the outside. Thanks.

Comment: @Glennzone If this is the route you have to take, consider a product like this. https://www.doityourself.com/forum/attachments/plumbing-piping/30568d1398439733-how-repair-cracked-spigot-no-inside-access-p5260076.jpg

Comment: @cutrightjm if you explained the link I would have upvoted the comment, but as it stands if the link breaks no one will have any idea what you are suggesting, I believe you are suggesting a trim piece to fix the cemented mess the op has.

Answer (score 0):

This is a freezeless faucet and it's a lot easier to replace the entire assembly especially since you have already uninstalled it. Your local home center should stock them in various lengths.
JACK showed one example. Here's another:
[image]

Comment: The big problem here is previous owner cemented the hell out of it and the vinyl is stuck. Idk how I’ll get to it without making a mess of the vinyl siding.